# Is Bi-direction RPC in Apache Avro Possible?

Tags: rpc, p2p, bidirectional, avro

Is it possible to do bi-directional (P2P) messaging in Apache Avro over a single connection?

Eg, if I defined a protocol in Avro with one method PING, is it possible for the PING request to be made by both clients without establishing a second connection?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?